# How can i manage a "ASP.NET MVC Actionlink" control to link to an action of a controller and data-toggle transactions at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am new to ASP.NET MVC so sometimes I have questions about it.This is one of them.

I have an actionlink and i want to link to an action of a controller and data-toggle transactions at the same time.

I added the code snippet below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Connections", "ConnectionIndex", "Connection", null, new { data_target = "#connectionSubmenu", data_toggle = "collapse", aria_expanded = "false", @class = "dropdown-toggle" })
 <ul class="collapse list-unstyled main" id="connectionSubmenu">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 </ul>
```

When I use the `ActionLink` in this way, only transaction of `data-toggle` runs but it doesn't link to the "view" that I give.

What can i do to manage that?Please help me.

Comment: Could you clarify something - is your goal to make the `ConnectionIndex` View appear inside the `ul` with the id of `connectionSubmenu`? when the data toggle link is clicked?

Comment: I want to make the "ul" expanded only and go to the view (ConnectionIndex) that i give at the same time.

Comment: ActionLink is supposed to link to an action method in a controller. It is up the action method to return the view you expect or not. May be you're barking to the wrong tree.

Comment: yes sorry,i have written wrong.I want to go to an action of a controller.

Comment: @Barsblue, when you call ActionLink, the action is "ConnectionIndex" and controller is "Connection" so it should render something like `<a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#connectionSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" href="/Connection/ConnectionIndex">Connections</a>` So what's the problem? The controller/action is there. If the link is correct perhaps you have some Javascript code messing up.

Comment: @Barsblue If I understand correctly, I don't think you can achieve what you want - you can either toggle the submenu on click or navigate to the link on click but not both. Perhaps consider showing the submenu on hover of the link, which can be achieved using a simple bit of CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp